# Correct way to write a pattern in C language

Tags: c, arrays, algorithm

I want to obtain the following output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
```

The code am running is as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i=1,flag=0,lines=0;  //0 for forward, 1 for reverse
    while(i!=0 && lines<3){
        if(!flag){
            printf("%d ",i);
            if(i==10){
                flag=1;
                printf("\n");
                lines++;
            }
            else
                i++;
        }
        else if(flag){
            printf("%d ",i);
            if(i==1){
                lines++;
                flag=0;
                printf("\n");
            }
            else
                i--;
         }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Am getting the desired output from the above code but not sure if it's an optimal code. Any other method/suggestion? Considering unlimited space but time complexity should be kept minimum.

**Condition**: Use only one loop

Comment: You should consider posting to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ instead for code review questions

Comment: `for( int i = 1; i <= 3; i ++ ) { if( i % 2 ) for( int j = 1; j <= 10; j++ ) printf( "%d ", j ); else for( int j = 10; j >= 1; j-- ) printf( "%d ", j ); printf("\n"); }`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @taskinoor Just because a question is on-topic elsewhere doesn't make it off-topic here. This has been discussed several times on meta. Code review is indeed a more suitable site to post this, but that does not make this question off-topic on SO.

Comment: Discussing performance without a specific system in mind in rather meaningless. Especially since 99% of the execution time in this case will be clogged up in the printf function calls. Unless you separate the algorithm from the printf calls, trying to optimize this loop is nothing but "pre-mature optimization". Optimization would also involve attempts to pre-generate the numbers at compile-time, getting rid of the loop entirely.

Comment: @Lundin thanks for the information. I definitely missed those meta discussions. Will keep that in my mind in future.

Comment: The most efficient code for a program with no explicit or implicit input parameters is just replication of the (static) output. Using one "loop" we get:
`do { printf("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10\n10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1\n1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10\n"); } while(0);`.  If the question is to be taken literally, this must be the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use forloops, minimize code that is repeated

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int lines, flag=1, val;

    for(lines=0;lines<3;lines++)
    {
            if(flag == 1)
                    for(val=1;val<=10;val++)
                            printf("%d ", val);
            else
                    for(val=10;val>0;val--)
                            printf("%d ", val);
            printf("\n");
            flag = -flag;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How exactly does this optimize anything? All you did was to make the code more readable.

Comment: less compares per value printed

Answer (score 0):

Use an array and iterate it normally at first iteration, vice versa in the second iteration and then normally again.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

void print_arr(int* array, int size);
void print_rev_arr(int* array, int size);

int main(void)
{
    int array[SIZE] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    int iter = 3;

    for(int i = 0; i < iter; ++i)
        if(i % 2)
            print_arr(array, SIZE);
        else
            print_rev_arr(array, SIZE);
    return 0;
}

void print_arr(int* array, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");
}

void print_rev_arr(int* array, int size)
{
    for(int i = size - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Output:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hint: you can use `for` loops to iterate in either direction:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; ++i)
```

or

```
for (int i = 10; i >= 1; --i)
```

Also, a `for` loop is better than a `while` here because it really shows to the reader "I am iterating `i` from this to that."

Answer (score 0):

IO completely dominates this problem.

But the fastest way to iterate forwards is

```
for(i=0;i<N;i++)
```

and the fastest and most elegant way to iterate backwards is

```
int i = N;
while(N--)
```

Comment: The fastest and most elegant way to iterate backwards is `for(i=0;i<N;i++)`. Then use `something[N-i-1]`

Comment: The problem with `while(N--)` is that very often `N` will be a constant, or a parameter that was passed into the function and that other code depends on. Pus, it depends on the rather arbitrary (and, in my opinion, idiotic) convention that 0 is considered false and any non-zero value is considered "not false."

Comment: I nodded. It should be while(i--).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

1. Use a for loop that will start from 1 and reach 10. Print its
   counter.
2. Use a for loop that will start from 10 and stop at 1. Print its
   counter.
3. Use a for loop that will start from 1 and reach 10. Print its
   counter.

Sample code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define LEN 10
#define ITER 3

int main(void)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < ITER; ++i)
    {
        if(i % 2)
            for(int j = 1; j <= LEN; ++j)
                printf("%d ", j);
        else
            for(int j = LEN; j >0; --j)
                printf("%d ", j);
        printf("\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -Wall main.c 
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ ./a.out 
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 things to consider.

First is whether the program is optimal or not. Is is quite easy to prove that your program is optimal (at least asymptotically optimal). You need to display 3n numbers, so you need at least 3n iterations. You have 3n iterations, so it's fine. You might be able to further optimize the iterations themselves, but that will arise as an implicit result of the second paragraph.

The second is readability. Your code is a bit verbose and unflexible. Consider the following:

```
int pattern[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
int patternSize = sizeof(pattern)/sizeof(int);
for (int i=0; i < 3; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<patternSize; j++) {
        if (i % 2)
            printf("%d", pattern[patternSize - j - 1]);
        else
            printf("%d", pattern[i])
    }
```

The code is shorter and clearer. Also, it is more maintable. It is clear what you have to do to chanelge the pattern. I could hardcode the pattern size as 10, but that would requite 2 changes when you change the pattern. I could generate the pattern, from the value of j, but that would limit the number of patterns that could be shown.

But what if the pattern is all the numbers from 1 to 200? Of course I'm not going to write them by hand. Just replace the array with a for loop that fills up the array. You don't have to change the code that displays the array. This is a small example of separation of concerns - one part of thr code does pattern generation, another part does the display, and they can be modified independently.

While this is asymptotically optimal, there are optimizations that can be made. For examples, using that array to store the pattern is not as efficient as generating the pattern from j. But in practice, unless more efficiency is needed, the advantages of this method outweigh the small performance penalty.

Comment: thank you for the deep insight I gained a lot of good points.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here's my take, I think it's more pleasant than most:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; ++j)
        {
            const int v = (i % 2) ? 10 - j : j + 1;
            printf("%d ", v);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Some points:

- Doesn't use an array, instead just generates the very simple pattern from the line number (`i`) and position (`j`).
- Not designed for "pluggable" patterns by using an array, since the pattern was very simplistic and repeating, that is exploited to simplify the code.
- Re-use the inner loop, rather than duplicating it.
- Prints a linefeed in the proper place, to actually get separate lines (not all posted solutions to that).

The inner loop's body could be shortened to a single line by folding `v` into the `printf()` of course, but I aimed for readability and clarity, there.